# Numpy version is not satisfied for tensorflow

Tags: python, r, numpy, tensorflow

I want to run a DNN model with tensorflow in R. The R package "tensorflow" makes it possible to write code in R, and train the model in the Python environment. The error is

> Error in py_dict_impl(keys, values, convert = convert) : 
>     Evaluation error: Required version of NumPy not available: installation of Numpy >= 1.6 not found

But the Numpy version on my computer is 1.15. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem ? I'm wondering, are you using reticulate ? What if you try to change [this line](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/master/R/package.R#L76) in the R package  ? 
It might be a bug that needs to raise an issue to RStudio ?

Comment: You could also just downgrade to an earlier version, e.g. `pip3 install 'numpy>=1.6.0,<1.10.0'`.